# How to count Columns in a table in Databricks Hive storage

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

This code is not working when inserted table name
no table found in information_schema.columns

select count(*)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'emp'

And this is not usefull
SHOW COLUMNS (FROM|IN) table_name [(FROM|IN) db_name

Even Describe table

Please suggest some other code to count the columns in a particular table.

Comment: Do you need to do that in pure SQL? Or python/scala also works?

Comment: spark.table("tablename").columns

Answer (score 1):

```
spark.sql("SHOW COLUMNS IN emp").count()
```

is a Scala or Python solution in a Databricks notebook. show columns returns a DataFrame with one column `col_name` and one row for each column, so counting the rows of that DF returns the number of columns in emp